# Flask : TypeError when deleting item

Tags: python, http, web, flask

I got error message 'Method Not Allowed' while I was working on delete method. What I wanted to do was when user click button, it sends a key which name is todo_id, and it delete item in database and redirects to the index.

This is views.py

```
@app.route('/delete_todo/<int:todo_id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_todo(todo_id):
    g.db.execute('''delete * from todo where todo_id = ?''', [todo_id])
    g.db.commit()
    flash('Your message was deleted')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

This is template

```
{% for todo in todo %}
  <li>{{ todo.text }}
 <small>&mdash; {{ todo.pub_date|datetimeformat }}</small>
 <a href="{{ url_for('delete_todo', todo_id=todo.todo_id) }}" class="button">Delete</a>
 {% else %}
    <small>None</small>
 {% endfor %}
```

EDIT 01 :

There was no error message, only 'Method Now Allowed' was displayed in browser,  so I changed  tag to  tag. Now it displays different message. I added changed template code and error message.

template

```
  <form action="{{ url_for('delete_todo', todo_id=todo.todo_id) }}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
 </form>
```

This is error message.
    TypeError
    TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1994, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in   handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in    full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

Comment: what's the full error message?

Comment: @HaleemurAli There is nothing in console, only 'Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.' displayed in browser.

Comment: @HaleemurAli Could it be the deleting protection of flask routing (especially the `POST` method) or database execution? At least, you can try to diagnose it step by step to gather more information.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but that DELETE syntax is not permitted.

Comment: You've got to do just: `'''delete from todo where todo_id = ?'''`

Comment: @bernie I changed DELETE to POST

Comment: yup, agree with @bernie the delete syntax is incorrect. also, I'm not sure `todo_id` needs to be put in a list in the argument to `execute`.

Comment: @HaleemurAli: yes it does actually need to be in a container of some sort: a list or tuple for example.

Comment: @bernie You mean I have to put todo_id in a list not in argument?

Comment: @camila: no the way you're doing it is fine

Comment: @bernie Than what kinds of solution I can use to solve this problem? I still  fail to passing argument..